# How to set Immutable Id of an MSOlUser to null value using powershell?

Tags: powershell, office365

I have tried the following command to set the immutable id of a user in Office 365

```
 Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName edwardlt501edwar@KT2.kb.co.in -ImmutableId $null
```

But when i try the following command it is actually returning an immutable id

```
Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName edwardlt501edwar@KT2.kb.co.in | select ImmutableId
```

Please let me know if there is some other way to set the immutable id to null?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName edwardlt501edwar@KT2.kb.co.in -ImmutableId "$null"
```

While executing the above command I got the following error:

*You must provide a required property: Parameter name:
FederatedUser.SourceAnchor*

While digging deep into the issue I got to know that we cannot clear immutable Id from a federated O365 account, instead we need to do the following:

1. Move the federated domain onto a managed domain:

   ```
   Set-MsolUserPrincipalName -UserPrincipalName edwardlt501edwar@KT2.kb.co.in  -NewUserPrincipalName edwardlt501edwar@<managed domain, usually something.onmicrosoft.com>
   ```
2. Set immutableid to null:

   ```
   Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName gw17edwardlt501edwar@<managed domain> -ImmutableId "$null"
   ```
3. Then wait for some time and assign a new immutable id:

   ```
   set-msolUser -userprincipalname gw17edwardlt501edwar@<managed domain> -immutableID f33fc1d2-73bd-4957-995f-37c83d349ef3
   ```
4. Move back to federated domain:

   ```
   Set-MsolUserPrincipalName -NewUserPrincipalName edwardlt501edwar@KT2.kb.co.in-UserPrincipalName edwardlt501edwar@<managed domain>
   ```
5. See the new immutable ID:

   ```
   Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName edwardlt501edwar@KT2.kb.co.in | select ImmutableId
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName edwardlt501edwar@KT2.kb.co.in -ImmutableId "$null"
```